# how to calculate precision, recall, and accuracy, if the label is not binary?

Tags: precision-recall, model-evaluation

I know how to evaluate the prediction performance if the label is binary, such as the classification label is `sick(yes/no)`.

The situation is the label is `sick(level1/level2/level3)`,in this situation, could we still calculate the precision? and how?

I feel confused in how to calculate TN/TP/FN/FP. I hope anyone can help me. And I understand R code, if needed, you can write in R or use any R package. For a better descript of data, it is kind like

```
label  x1   x2
1      21   123
1      223  22
2      22   1
3      8    9
```

Comment: One option is to merge two classes so you just have the normal binary situation. Terms like precision/recall (generally used in information retrieval) and sensitivity/specificity (generally used in medicine) only work in the binary situation. Accuracy will still work (simply proportion of classifications which are exactly correct).

Comment: Also you haven't described your data very well. I certainly don't understand it...

Comment: Would I be correct in guessing that each row is a data point with x1 and x2 intended to be predictors?

Comment: @tristan hi, just consider it is a simple number matrix. The first column is label. The label has simple linear relationship with other col. The label can be 1 or 2 or 3. For example, label of test data is 1,2,3,1, and prediction is 1,2,2,1. So just tell me how to calculate the true negative?

Comment: True negative doesn't necessarily mean anything in your case. Can you describe the states perhaps, e.g., are they increasing severity, is level 1 no disease?

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the confusion matrix, the cross-tabulation of observed and predicted classes. A confusion matrix is 2x2 in binary classification: Predicted (True and False) by Observed (True and False). A confusion matrix is k-by-k in multi-class, where k is the number of classes.

[image: confusion_matrix_example]

The positive/correct cells will be on the diagonal (e.g., predict sick-level1 and observed sick-level1). The negative/incorrect cells on the off diagonal and will be segmented by type. There are 2 ways to make a misprediction:

1. Predict sick-level1 but observed sick-level2
2. Predict sick-level1 but observed sick-level3

The best R package is [caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) and use the `confusionMatrix` function.